# Python: How can I change the x axis interval to show 12 months using matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a chart showing data during a whole year. The data is from a CSV file (records.csv), which is as below:

```
month,data
2016-01,66
2016-02,68
2016-03,70
2016-04,72
2016-05,74
2016-06,76
2016-07,78
2016-08,80
2016-09,82
2016-10,84
2016-11,86
2016-12,88
```

My code is as below:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def date_to_list(index):
    """ save date to a list """
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(datetime.strptime(row[index], '%Y-%m'))
    return results

def data_to_list(index):
    """ save data to a list """
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(int(row[index]))
    return results


filename = 'records.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(data)
    data = list(data)

    # save data and date to list
    records = data_to_list(1)
    date = date_to_list(0)

    plt.plot(date, records)
    plt.show()
```

Then I've got a chart like below:
[image]

Currently I'm struggling with below two issues:

1. The x axis here only shows 6 months, how can I get 12 months? Or in
   another way to say, how can I change the interval as I want, e.g. by
   months/quarter/year?
2. There are some space in the left and right side of the line, I guess
   it's also due to the x axis range. How can I make the line directly
   start (& end) from the left (& right) side of the rectangle area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to set the position of ticks, you can use a `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator`. In order to have the ticks have a specific format, you may use a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`. In order for the ticklabels not to overlap, you may use `autofmt_xdate()`. In order to have no margins, you may use `plt.margins(x=0,y=0)`:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator()) 
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.margins(x=0,y=0)
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
data = u"""month,data
2016-01,66
2016-02,68
2016-03,70
2016-04,72
2016-05,74
2016-06,76
2016-07,78
2016-08,80
2016-09,82
2016-10,84
2016-11,86
2016-12,88"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import matplotlib.dates
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import io

def date_to_list(index):
    """ save date to a list """
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(datetime.strptime(row[index], '%Y-%m'))
    return results

def data_to_list(index):
    """ save data to a list """
    results = []
    for row in data:
        results.append(int(row[index]))
    return results

with io.StringIO(data) as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(data)
    data = list(data)

    # save data and date to list
    records = data_to_list(1)
    date = date_to_list(0)

    plt.plot(date, records)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator())
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.margins(x=0,y=0)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom labels with `labels = [i[0] for i in data]` and custom ticks and range on your x axis with

```
xvalues = np.arange(0, len(labels), 1)
plt.xticks(xvalues, labels)
plt.xlim(-0.5, len(labels) - 0.5)
```

This will produce a label for each month in the style you used in the question. The x limits are chosen such that the ticks are centered. However, note that the x axis gets messed up a bit. In order to avoid this, you can either:

1. Stretch your plot in the x direction.
2. Drastically reduce your font size.
3. Consider reducing the number of labels shown in the plot.
   [image]

Comment: There is still some margin around the line. The best way not to mess up the axes, is to rotate the labels.